Get count and date from table and count and date from another table in one query
I have a query that gets a count and date from a table.  It looks like this:
SELECT 
 date(`date`) as 'Date'
 , sb.`send_id`
 , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' 
FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`;

This gets me results that look like this:
|    DATE    |   SEND_ID    |   SUBS    |
-----------------------------------------
| 2024-09-01 |  1111111     |    1900   | 
| 2024-09-01 |  2222222     |    1835   | 
| 2024-09-02 |  1111111     |    264    | 
| 2024-09-02 |  2222222     |    26     | 
-----------------------------------------

I have a second query that looks like this:
SELECT 
  date(`o_date`)
  , `o_send_id`
  , count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
FROM `table2`
WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`;

This gets me results that looks like this:
|    O_DATE    |   O_SEND_ID    |   UNITS  |
--------------------------------------------
| 2024-09-01   |    1111111     |    107   | 
| 2024-09-01   |    2222222     |    360   | 
| 2024-09-02   |    1111111     |    223   | 
| 2024-09-02   |    2222222     |    209   | 
--------------------------------------------    

What I am trying to do is JOIN these table to get the SUB and UNITS displayed.
So the results would look something like this:
|    DATE    |   SEND_ID    |   SUBS    |   UNITS |
---------------------------------------------------
| 2024-09-01 |  1111111     |    1900   |   107   |
| 2024-09-01 |  2222222     |    1835   |   360   |
| 2024-09-02 |  1111111     |    264    |   223   |
| 2024-09-02 |  2222222     |    26     |   209   |
---------------------------------------------------

Here was my attempt to JOIN the tables on a single date:
SELECT 
  date(tb1.`date`) as 'Date'
  , tb1.`send_id`
  , count(tb1.`id`) as 'SUBS' 
  , count(tb2.`id`) as 'UNITS'
FROM `table1` tb1
JOIN `table2` tb2 ON tb2.`o_send_id` = tb1.`send_id` AND tb2.`o_date` = tb1.`date`
WHERE (tb1.`date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%')
GROUP BY date(tb1.`date`), tb1.`send_id`;

It runs for a little bit but eventually conks out.  I'm assuming it's because there quite a few records (in the millions).  I get an error that reads:
Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost.
Please check your network connectivity and server status.

So I tried to run the same query but this time just use 1 date and 1 send_id, like this:
SELECT 
  date(tb1.`date`) as 'Date'
  , tb1.`send_id`
  , count(tb1.`id`) as 'SUBS' 
  , count(tb2.`id`) as 'UNITS'
FROM `table1` tb1
JOIN `table2` tb2 ON tb2.`o_send_id` = tb1.`send_id` AND tb2.`o_date` = tb1.`date`
WHERE (tb1.`date` LIKE '2024-09-30%') AND tb1.`send_id` = '1111111'
GROUP BY date(tb1.`date`), tb1.`send_id`;    

This query runs, but I get a result that looks like this:
|    DATE    |   SEND_ID    |   SUBS     |   UNITS   |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2024-09-30 |  1111111     |    35960   |   35960   |
------------------------------------------------------

Where as the query was successful in running, the I'm not sure what happened to the SUBS and UNITS, as they came in with the same 36960 result.  The totals should be different, and no way should they be that high.
Not sure what I did wrong.
In a previous question I asked, someone suggested that I post the table description.
Here is the description for table1:
| Field   |   Type        | Null | Key  | Default |         Extra       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id      | int(11)       |  NO  |  PRI |  NULL   |  AUTO_INCREMENT     |  
| send_id | varchar(255)  |  YES |      |  NULL   |                     |   
| date    | datetime      |  YES |      |  NULL   |                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

And here is the description of table2:
| Field     |   Type        | Null | Key  | Default |         Extra       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id        | int(11)       |  NO  |  PRI |  NULL   |  AUTO_INCREMENT     |  
| o_send_id | varchar(255)  |  YES |      |  NULL   |                     |    
| o_date    | datetime      |  YES |      |  NULL   |                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  

Nothing special in the descriptions of each table.
With all of this said, help me figure out how I can get the SUBS count and UNIT counts to display in the same query.
The indexes for table1 are below.

And here are the indexes for table2.

I am only using the ID.

Please show us your indexes. Changing o_send_id to be a big integer might help with performance and table size.

@Schwern - o_send_id is just a placeholder for Stackoverflow.  It is actually a VARCHAR with letters and numbers.

And what are your indexes?

That explains the performance problems; indexes are critical to SQL performance. Use show index and read Use The Index, Luke.

@Schwern - I see the indexes.  In my table description, I changed the name of the fields for Stackoverflow.  I don't have time to keep changing the names of stuff, so I'm going to update the question with a screenshot showing the indexes.

Screenshots are hard to read and work with and will make it harder to answer your question. Please post your indexes as text.

We also don't know how the columns in your screenshot relate to the columns in your question. Note, you have redundant indexes on email.

@JohnBeasley on your previous question there are answers mentioning the performance part, why don't you even consider those suggestions ? Not the first answer is always the best. As per next questions, run show create table tableName to show table description, including indexes

You can join your 2 queries as
select coalesce(first.Date,second.Date) as `date`
  ,coalesce(first.`send_id`,second.`send_id`)
  ,coalesce(first.SUBS,0) Subs
  ,coalesce(first.UNI,0) Uni
from
(  SELECT 
   date(`date`) as 'Date'
   , sb.`send_id`
   , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' 
  FROM `table1`
  WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`
 )first
left join (
  SELECT date(`o_date`)
    , `o_send_id`
    , count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`
)second on first.date=second.date and first.send_id=second.send_id

If date or o_send_id is exists in 1 subquery output and not exists in another, you may lost rows.
Update1:
More reliable case



id
date
send_id




1
2024-09-01
100


2
2024-09-01
101


3
2024-09-02
101






id
o_date
o_send_id




1
2024-09-01
100


2
2024-09-01
101


3
2024-09-01
101


4
2024-09-11
104



select `date`
  ,send_id
  ,sum(Subs) subs
  ,sum(UNI)  Uni
from
(  SELECT date(`date`) as `date`, `send_id` , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' ,0 UNI
  FROM `table1`
  WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`
  union all
  SELECT date(`o_date`) `date` , `o_send_id` ,0 SUBS ,count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`
)u
group by `date`,send_id





date
send_id
subs
Uni




2024-09-01
100
1
1


2024-09-01
101
1
2


2024-09-02
101
1
0


2024-09-11
104
0
1



Update2:
In first example, we lost date=2024-09-11' and send_id=104
select coalesce(first.Date,second.Date) as `date`
  ,coalesce(first.`send_id`,second.`o_send_id`) send_id
  ,coalesce(first.SUBS,0) Subs
  ,coalesce(second.UNI,0) Uni
  ,first.*, second.*
from
(  SELECT 
   date(`date`) as 'Date'
   , `send_id`
   , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' 
  FROM `table1`
  WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`
 )first
left join (
  SELECT date(`o_date`) Date
    , `o_send_id`
    , count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
  GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`
)second on first.date=second.date and first.send_id=second.o_send_id




date
send_id
Subs
Uni
Date
send_id
SUBS
Date
o_send_id
UNI




2024-09-01
100
1
1
2024-09-01
100
1
2024-09-01
100
1


2024-09-01
101
1
2
2024-09-01
101
1
2024-09-01
101
2


2024-09-02
101
1
0
2024-09-02
101
1
null
null
null



fiddle

A composite index on (send_id, date) or perhaps ((date(date)), send_id) would likely improve performance of all your queries.

Rather than joining the tables, you can join your grouped queries.
Note: You don't need to add a % to a between dates query, MySQL is probably ignoring it. Do explicitly cast it to date as recommended in the docs.
with table1_count as (
  SELECT 
   date(`date`) as 'Date'
   , sb.`send_id`
   , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' 
  FROM `table1`
  WHERE `date` BETWEEN date('2024-09-01') AND date('2024-09-30')
  GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`
),
table2_count as (
  SELECT 
    date(`o_date`) as 'Date'
    , `o_send_id`
    , count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN date('2024-09-01') AND date('2024-09-30')
  GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`
)
select 
  t1c.date,
  t1c.send_id,
  t1c.subs,
  t2c.uni
from table1_count t1c
left join table2_count t2c on 
  t1c.date = t2c.date and 
  t1c.send_id = t2c.o_send_id
order by t1c.date, t1c.subs

The downside of this approach is if any days are missing from table1, but are in table2, they will not appear in the query.
Since you're on MySQL 5.7 which does not have with, they can be rewritten using subqueries.
select 
  t1c.date,
  t1c.send_id,
  t1c.subs,
  t2c.uni
from (
  SELECT 
    date(`date`) as 'Date'
    , sb.`send_id`
    , count(`id`) as 'SUBS' 
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN date('2024-09-01') AND date('2024-09-30')
    GROUP BY date(`date`), `send_id`
) t1c
left join (
  SELECT 
    date(`o_date`) as 'Date'
    , `o_send_id`
    , count(`id`) AS 'UNI'
  FROM `table2`
  WHERE `o_date` BETWEEN date('2024-09-01') AND date('2024-09-30')
  GROUP BY date(`o_date`), `o_send_id`
) t2c on 
  t1c.date = t2c.date and 
  t1c.send_id = t2c.o_send_id
order by t1c.date, t1c.subs


I can't use WITH, as the MySQL version is only 5.7.  I know, I know.  I've already brought up that the version needs to be updated.

I'm just going to have to extract the data from both queries and put it in an excel sheet, then run a vlookup and/or pivot.

@JohnBeasley Please add that version information to your question, it's important. The CTEs can be done as subqueries instead.

I wanted to thank you for your help.  Not sure who downvoted you, but I fixed that.  I went with the answer provided by ValKink.
